# Unity - Android - BLE Bluetooth Permissions

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-permissions

I'm wondering whether anyone knows whether it is possible to connect a Bluetooth low energy module to an Android device without asking for location permissions or bringing up the companion device pairing screen.

I have created a unity project that attempts to connect to the BLE device, and I've tested this on IOS and the connection works smoothly and without issue, however when loaded onto an Android device I am met with the Companion Device Pairing screen, which displays a whole list of different wifi and bluetooth devices. Once selected, another screen requesting permission for access to the users location appears. This whole process is fairly clunky, and although and I am able to connect eventually, often the application quits or repeatedly brings up the companion device pairing screen and prevents the application from fully loading or connecting to the BLE device.

I believe that these are being raised due to the android manifest file (which I have included below) containing reference to both of these functions. When I remove these however, the application fails to open, often crashing or quitting upon start.

Alternatively if these are required, might it be possible that someone could offer some advice on how to implement a filter on the companion device search (so that I can only list relevant BLE devices rather than a long list of all WIFI and Bluetooth devices). I've found reference to this on the official android developer site, however I'm having some trouble figuring out how to correctly implement this within my unity project.

**Companion Device Filter link :**

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/companion-device-pairing#filter

**Manifest File :**

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION"/>

<uses-permission-sdk-23 android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>

<uses-permission-sdk-23 android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_COMPANION_RUN_IN_BACKGROUND"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_COMPANION_USE_DATA_IN_BACKGROUND"/>

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth_le" android:required="true"/>

<uses-feature android:name="android.software.companion_device_setup"/>
```

If anyone is able to offer any advice it would be very much appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Do you need to use Companion Device Pairing?

Comment: My understanding from reading over the android developer description was that by using Companion Device Pairing, I would be able to avoid requesting permission  for the users location when connecting to the device (which if possible I'd really like to do). I've tried to remove the reference to this within the manifest file, however this seems to result in the application crashing or quitting.

Comment: Including Companion Device pairing should allow you to get rid of the "ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" permission. Without Companion Device pairing you would still need to allow the location request, but only once. You can filter the BLE devices without a prompt and only need to ask something if there are multiple devices to choose from

Comment: Thank you. If possible I'd prefer to use Companion Device pairing so as to avoid the prompt for the users location. I don't suppose you have a rough idea of how to implement a bluetooth device filter so that only BLE devices show up? Currently I'm getting a whole list of WIFI, Bluetooth Classic and BLE devices. I'm not quite sure how to implement this within Unity. Not a problem if not, and thank you for your time and help!

Answer (score 0):

For filtering the Companion Device pairing dialog take a look at [this guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/companion-device-pairing#filter) from google.

You have the option to either set `setSingleDevice()` to `true` and only display one device to choose from or filter the list using a [DeviceFilter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/companion/DeviceFilter) of one of these types:

- [BluetoothDeviceFilter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/companion/BluetoothDeviceFilter)
- [BluetoothLeDeviceFilter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/companion/BluetoothLeDeviceFilter)
- [WifiDeviceFilter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/companion/WifiDeviceFilter)

This could look like this:

```
BluetoothDeviceFilter deviceFilter = new BluetoothDeviceFilter.Builder()
        // Match only Bluetooth devices whose name matches the pattern.
        .setNamePattern(Pattern.compile("My device"))
        // Match only Bluetooth devices whose service UUID matches this pattern.
        .addServiceUuid(new ParcelUuid(new UUID(0x123abcL, -1L)), null)
        .build();
```

Comment: Thank you Michael. I did come across this already, but was mainly unsure of how to implement this within Unity. I'm using C sharp script to make the connection and was unsure of how to use this code given that it is written in Kotlin / Java. I apologize for my lack of understanding here, I'm trying to understand how to use it but have limited knowledge within this area.

Comment: Oh, sorry! I overlooked the unity part. I don't have any experiences in integrating Android and Unity, sorry

Comment: Not a problem Michael, thank you for your help regardless. I'm going to continue looking into this so if I find out how I'll be sure to leave the results here.